# Animation of two groups of particles/spheres switching sides and colliding

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation, collections, force-fields

I am currently trying to switch to Blender from some other 3D modeling/animating environments. Unfortunately, I found some troubles with force fields' animations and it makes me quite frustrated for the past two/three days. I hope you can help me out.

Please let me start with a description of what I would like to achieve:

Two groups of particles (or different-size spheres to be precise) that are attracted to two opposite sides of the box (up and down). They should act like they always have opposing gravity vectors. So when one group goes up, the other falls down. During the sides' switch, they should collide and interact like a regular rigid body. I would like to repeat the simulation and switch their sides 2-3 times. I have made an illustration so you can better understand what I mean (black and white arrows demonstrate the direction of the particles' attraction):
[image: behaviour demo]

What I have tried was to use force and charge fields and attach them to the different collections (with shift + M shortcut) while setting the rigid body to work with both collections at the same time. Unfortunately, it doesn't work and the forces influence both groups.

I have also tried somehow setting opposite gravity vectors for each group but I couldn't find a suitable option.

Is there any way to set a force field to affect only one collection while it can still collide with the other one on the rigid body principles? Have anyone tried to achieve similar results?

I have walked through many tutorials and the blender's documentation but I couldn't find the right answers. Also, the collection description and its usage seems to be quite brief not fully covering the whole topic.

Comment: “I tried somehow setting different gravity vectors, but could not find a suitable solution.” What exactly was unsuitable about it? Because, I would expect that to work great.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The thing is that I couldn't set different values for each collection. Could you please let me know or send any reference on how to do this properly?

Comment: I have also double-checked the Blender's documentation, and it says that "Gravity is a **global** setting that is applied to all physics systems in a scene". So it seems that there is no way to set it differently for each collection. Am I wrong?

Comment: I've done some research and experimentation, and Blender particles cannot collide with each other. I think you'll have to use rigid bodies.

Comment: As for gravity, I thought there was a local gravity setting for particle systems, but I couldn't find it, so I just turned it off and used force fields in collections. Everything works except that the particles do not interact with each-other.

Comment: t looks like we're on the same page now and this is the point where I am stuck at ;) Currently I have some sphere objects divided into two collections and all of them are active rigid bodies. In the parent collection, I have a passive rigid body container. Spheres can collide with each other and the container properly but the difficulty right now is how to make them being attracted to the opposite sides and how to reverse these directions within the next simulation stage. I really cannot get this why you cannot set the objects affected by the force field. It seems like an absolute basics.

Comment: There is also one thing that really seems to work differently than it is described in the documentation and it is the charge force field. Accordingly to the description it is "based ON THE CHARGE of particles" and "ONLY influences other charge force fields" and it doesn't seem to behave that way. In physics, if we have two particles with low + and - charges, and we add two planes with higher + and - charges, the "+" particle will be attracted to the "-" plane and repelled by the "+" plane. The same rule will apply to the other particle. Well, it doesn't seem to work like that in Blender.